# Automatic Time Conversion in AWS to Snowflake

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I'm using Python in Google's App Engine to cache fields from AWS to Snowflake. The issue is that all the times in Snowflake have 7 hours added, when I'm not doing anything in the Python code to change the time.

Are there specific settings to handle this in Snowflake, i.e. set it to take the literal timestamp and not one adjusted?

AWS

```
ID|Minute of INSERTED AT
1|Jun 30, 2020 01:49
```

SF

```
ID|Minute of INSERTED AT
1|Jun 30, 2020 08:49
```

There's no documentation saying as such but I've never been able to come across anyone coming across such an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snowflake has an account parameter for time zone. That cascades down from account to user, and from user to session.

```
select current_timestamp(); -- This will show you the time zone offset for the session.
alter session set TIMEZONE = 'Etc/UTC'; --This will set to UTC
select current_timestamp(); -- Confirm it's set to offset +0000
```

Comment: Yea I just found that out before I saw your answer! In Data->General it has Time Zone Support = Time Zone by default for me. This needed to be set to Disabled and then agreed with AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Datetime in Google's Datastore (GAE) is in UTC [1]. I think the same principle applies to Snowflake. Based on that, you should have your code make the necessary adjustment for UTC time.

1. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#Date_and_Time